# What's the closest thing I can get to a table with double heading (row and column) and inner top and left outlines?

Tags: tables

Here's the result I'd like to get:

[image]

I couldn't come up with anything close and not sure how to look for something like this. Help please!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why can't you use a single \hline in the table after the first row and a single | between the first and second column in the alignment definition (e.g. {c|cccc}).

Comment: @Plergux: Yep, that actually worked as intended, thanks!

Comment: ok. I'll write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating `tabular`s a combination of `\hline` and `|` can be used to create various effects in your tables. E.g.:

```
\begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
x  &  0  &  e  & x  &  x+i \\
\hline
1  &  0  &  1  & x  &  x+i \\
x  &  0  &  e  & x  &  x+i \\
1  &  0  &  1  & x  &  x+i \\
x  &  0  &  e  & x  &  x+i \\
\end{tabular}
```

makes:

[image]